# ECS Task Definition Update Not Triggering Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

When I update the task definition for one of my ECS services, the service does not re-deploy with the new task definition until I run `aws ecs update-service ... --force-new-deployment`. Is there some kind of configuration option that controls this behaviour? I've noticed that some of my services do re-deploy when I update the Task Definition, but others don't and I'm not sure why that is.

I've provisioned my infrastructure with terraform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `force_new_deployment` setting in the `aws_ecs_service` resource in your Terraform code.